# Windows Experience Index doesn't complete, HAL error in event viewer

Tags: windows-8, macbook-pro, event-log, windows-experience-index, microsoft-expression

So, I was just randomly digging around my laptop and found a couple of weird things. First, the Windows Experience Index goes through its motions, completes all the tests and then throws up this error:

[image]

First, I assumed Windows was just paranoid and tried it again but the same result. I ran `sfc /scannow` and no clues there. I googled and saw many people have a problem with WEI so I let it pass. But when I was digging the event viewer, I found this among a bunch of harmless Warnings

`The platform firmware has corrupted memory across the previous system memory transition. Please check for updated firmware for your system`

[image]

After some more googling, I found that is due to outdated BIOS firmware. However, this is on an Apple MacBook Pro 9,1 Mid 2012 15 inch non retina which also doesn't have BIOS as such. Bootcamp apparently uses some sort of BIOS emulator (forgive me, I don't know the technical details). Well, the error sounds alarming enough to me and I just clubbed them as I thought they're related. The HAL error comes after I wake up the system from sleep but it doesn't come every time. Just sometimes. Is my registry borked or something? Or is it nothing to worry about?

I have also noticed that Expression Studio refuses to install (it worked fine on Windows 7) saying license key is invalid. A Microsoft Support article gave a Fixit (and also says it is a registry issue) but that is only for Windows 7 and when I run it, it says incompatible system (I'm on Windows 8 Pro).

Sorry for posting so many errors at once but I just feel they're somehow related to each other. I have done a refresh and reset (yes, both) in the past and it doesn't help. These things somehow keep popping up.

EDIT: WinSat.log file is uploaded here: http://sdrv.ms/Wx8XB9

Comment: Open the file "C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\winsat.log" and look for the complete error message.

Comment: Can't understand anything in the log file

Comment: upload the log file to your SkyDrive or Dropbox and paste a link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Added

Comment: ok, you get the error "exe\processwinsaterror.cpp:0298: Unspecified error 48 occured." 

This user has the same issue:

http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/2599-show-us-your-wei-9.html#post94095

But I have no idea how to fix this. Disable all 3rd party tools (like Antivirus tools) and try to run WinSAT again.

Comment: And what about the hal error?

Comment: update the BIOS. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028443

Comment: I'm on a MacBook. Apple gives me a BIOS emulator

Comment: update the UEFI Firmware.

Comment: Umm... how to do that?

Comment: I don't know how Apple handles this. Normal users go to the website of their motherboard manufacture. You should look at the Apple support pages.

Comment: Well, we have Apple Software Update which gives such updates to drivers and the rest and that shows nothing. And btw this isn't on UEFI, this is on a BIOS emulator which Apple has made for Windows to run

Comment: if this tool doesn't detect anything, ignore this entry. Does WinSAT now work?

Comment: I dug out the cause for WEI. I use a driver called Trackpad++ for the trackpad. Apparently that prevents WEI from completing its job. I have reported the bug to the author.

Comment: Anyways I don't care for WEI. I was just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a corrupted DLL file somewhere. Refresh solved it.